# Same measure ID/name conflict (SQL Server AMO)

Tags: sql-server, olap

I am currently importing two measure groups from two different cubes in a single new cube. There is a measure with the same name in the two cubes, when I import the measures in the new cube I get an error during cube processing because of the duplicate ID. How can I avoid this? I am using AMO to build the cube pro grammatically. (SQL Server 2005/2008)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the measure Id with XMLA.

In Management Studio, rightclik on one of the two original cubes > Script As > Alter 
Look for the measure you want to change and change the `<Measure><Id>` node to a different Id.
Execute the XMLA, and then proceed to merge the two cubes. It should work.